# JSON file to HTML table using localhost API to get data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I keep getting the below error when I try to create a HTML table with the JSON data :

```
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at requestJSON6
```

Below is my JSON:

```
{
    "AAPL": [
        {
            "expenses": {
                "0": "1920000.00",
                "1": "1920000.00",
                "2": "1920000.00",
                "3": "1920000.00",
                "4": "1920000.00"
            },
            "dt_posted": {
                "0": "2022-10-20T21:53:30-04:00",
                "1": "2022-10-20T21:53:30-04:00",
                "2": "2022-10-20T21:53:30-04:00",
                "3": "2022-10-20T21:53:30-04:00",
                "4": "2022-10-20T21:53:30-04:00"
            },
            "description": {
                "0": "Providing information related to Apple Pay",
                "1": "Issues related to technology platform liability Issues related to content moderation",
                "2": "Issues related to transparency and government access to data, including H.R. 7072/S. 4373, the Non-Disclosure Order (NDO) Fairness Act",
                "3": "Issues related tothe requirements of E.O. 14028, an Executive Order on Improving the Nation's Cybersecurity Issues related to cybersecurity requirements in H.R. 7900, the National Defense Authorization Act for Fiscal Year 2023",
                "4": "Issues related to the domestic manufacturing of semiconductors, including funding for the previously enacted CHIPS for America Act; S. 1260, the United States Innovation and Competition Act; and H.R. 4521, America COMPETES Act Providing information related to Apples supply chain"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my code, it works fine with other JSON files so not sure what this issue is.

```
const requestUrl6 = 'https://api.npoint.io/1cae29b5fc8900f6cc5a';
const requestJSON6 = async url => {

  const response6 = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  const limit6 = Math.max(...Object.keys(response6.expenses)) + 1;
  for(let index6 = 0; index6 < limit6; index6++)
  {
      let newRow6 = rowTemplate6.cloneNode(true);
      newRow6.id = '';
      newRow6.querySelector('.Expenses6').innerHTML = response6.expenses[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Date6').innerHTML = response6.date[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Purpose6').innerHTML = response6.sharesHeld[index6];
      rowTemplate6.parentNode.appendChild(newRow6);
  }
  rowTemplate6.parentNode.removeChild(rowTemplate6); 
}
requestJSON6(requestUrl6);
```

Comment: What about the `AAPL` key? You’re just ignoring it.

Comment: You're right, my other json files that work don't have this I've just checked.  How can I add it in? @SebastianSimon

Comment: Rolled back your edit which included the answer in the question post. Please read the [etiquette for answering your own question](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/289905). Answers belong only in the Answer section, whereas only questions belong in the Question section.

Answer (score 3):

You miss a few steps while unnesting your object.

```
const requestJSON6 = async url => {

  const response6 = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  const limit6 = Math.max(...Object.keys(response6.expenses)) + 1; //Here response6.expenses doesn't exist, instead you want to access response6.AAPL[0].expenses
  for(let index6 = 0; index6 < limit6; index6++)
  {
      let newRow6 = rowTemplate6.cloneNode(true);
      newRow6.id = '';
      newRow6.querySelector('.Expenses6').innerHTML = response6.expenses[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Date6').innerHTML = response6.date[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Purpose6').innerHTML = response6.sharesHeld[index6];
      rowTemplate6.parentNode.appendChild(newRow6);
  }
  rowTemplate6.parentNode.removeChild(rowTemplate6); 
}
```

Something like this would allow you to browse all keys :

```
const requestUrl6 = 'https://api.npoint.io/1cae29b5fc8900f6cc5a';
const requestJSON6 = async url => {

  const response6 = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  const keys = Object.keys(response6);
  for (let keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < keys.length; keyIndex++){
  const limit6 = Math.max(...Object.keys(response6[keys[keyIndex]][0].expenses)) + 1; //Note here that i take the first entry of the sub-array
  for(let index6 = 0; index6 < limit6; index6++)
  {
      let newRow6 = rowTemplate6.cloneNode(true);
      newRow6.id = '';
      newRow6.querySelector('.Expenses6').innerHTML = response6.expenses[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Date6').innerHTML = response6.date[index6];
      newRow6.querySelector('.Purpose6').innerHTML = response6.sharesHeld[index6];
      rowTemplate6.parentNode.appendChild(newRow6);
  }
  rowTemplate6.parentNode.removeChild(rowTemplate6); }
}
```

Like noted in the comment, this would just take the first entry of the sub-array of "AAPL", which according to your objects could pose some issue like :

1. If the array is empty, which would cause `Object.keys(response6[keys[keyIndex]][0]` to be undefined, causing again a similar issue
2. If any other entries could be interesting for you
   In these cases, best would be adding the necessary check and/or array traversal to handle these cases.

Comment: Thank you! I have another question regarding this same issue that I think you might be able to answer if possible :) @EliottBouvard

Comment: Sure @kiestuthridge23, what is your issue ?

Comment: The issue i'm getting is: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"                                I can't post a new question as there is a time limit between each psoting of questions @EliottBouvard

Comment: What is the endpoint who give you the wrong JSON ?

Comment: https://api.npoint.io/1cae29b5fc8900f6cc5a

Comment: My new question is now up if you can check it out:) @EliottBouvard